# Is it possible to declare the type of the variable in Rust for loops?

Tags: rust

C++ example:

```
for (long i = 0; i < 101; i++) {
    //...
}
```

In Rust I tried:

```
for i: i64 in 1..100 {
    // ...
}
```

I could easily just declare a `let i: i64 =` var before the for loop
but I'd rather learn the correct way to doing this, but this resulted in

```
error: expected one of `@` or `in`, found `:`
 --> src/main.rs:2:10
  |
2 |     for i: i64 in 1..100 {
  |          ^ expected one of `@` or `in` here
```

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You can use an [integer suffix](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/tokens.html#numbers) on one of the literals you've used in the range. Type inference will do the rest:

```
for i in 1i64..101 {
    println!("{}", i);
}
```

Comment: Going down the type ascription approach, `range({ let x: i64 = 1; x }, 100)` would also work. Of course, I don’t recommend that you actually *do* that.

Comment: can this be used for custom types ? and what about an element in a tuple ?

Comment: Suffixes for numeric literals are built into the language. I don't know what you mean by "in a tuple." Certainly, `(1u64, 2f32)` works just fine. Perhaps it would be better to ask a new question?

Comment: One really should be able to do `for i: u8 in 0..26`.

Answer (score 22):

No, it is **not** possible to declare the type of the variable in a `for` loop.

Instead, a more general approach (e.g. applicable also to `enumerate()`) is to introduce a `let` binding by destructuring the item inside the body of the loop.

Example:

```
for e in bytes.iter().enumerate() {
    let (i, &item): (usize, &u8) = e; // here
    if item == b' ' {
        return i;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also use `(_, &u8)` if you want to omit the `usize` part

Answer (score 4):

If your loop variable happens to be the result of a function call that returns a generic type:

```
let input = ["1", "two", "3"];
for v in input.iter().map(|x| x.parse()) {
    println!("{:?}", v);
}
```

```
error[E0284]: type annotations required: cannot resolve `<_ as std::str::FromStr>::Err == _`
 --> src/main.rs:3:37
  |
3 |     for v in input.iter().map(|x| x.parse()) {
  |                                     ^^^^^
```

You can use a *turbofish* to specify the types:

```
for v in input.iter().map(|x| x.parse::<i32>()) {
//                                   ^^^^^^^
    println!("{:?}", v);
}
```

Or you can use the *fully-qualified syntax*:

```
for v in input.iter().map(|x| <i32 as std::str::FromStr>::from_str(x)) {
//                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    println!("{:?}", v);
}
```

See also:

- [How do I imply the type of the value when there are no type parameters or ascriptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41882151/155423)

Answer (score 4):

Try casting with [as](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/keyword.as.html):

```rust
for i in 1..100 as i64 {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: In my opinion, this is more readable for interpreting the datatype, as well as changing it long term. Compared to `for i in 0u8..100 {`, `for i in 0..100 as u8 {` is much easier to work with.

Answer (score 2):

There [used to be a discussion](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/354#issuecomment-257967827) where this was requested, which was followed up by an actual [RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/2522).

It seems like the discussion was postponed, though, because not enough people really cared about the topic.

Currently, if you absolutely want to annotate, it seems like the best option you have is:

```
fn main() {
    let my_vec: Vec<i32> = vec![-1, 22, -333];
    for i in my_vec.iter() {
        let _: &i32 = i;
        println!("{}", i);
    }
}
```

As you can see, this fails if the type doesn't match:

```
fn main() {
    let my_vec: Vec<i32> = vec![-1, 22, -333];
    for i in my_vec.iter() {
        let _: &i16 = i;
        println!("{}", i);
    }
}
```

```
 --> src/main.rs:4:23
  |
4 |         let _: &i16 = i;
  |                ----   ^ expected `i16`, found `i32`
  |                |
  |                expected due to this
  |
  = note: expected reference `&i16`
             found reference `&i32`
```

Of course due to automatic dereferencing this method cannot differentiate between `&i32` and `&&i32`, which might be a problem in some cases:

```
fn main() {
    let my_vec: Vec<i32> = vec![-1, 22, -333];
    for i in my_vec.iter() {
        let _: &i32 = &i; // Compiles, but the right side is &&i32
        println!("{}", i);
    }
}
```

But in general this should bring enough confidence to potential reviewers, in my opinion.