# How do I imply the type of the value when there are no type parameters or ascriptions?

Tags: rust

I am trying to convert my struct into a `HashMap`, but I am unable to do so while being in the impl block. Due to a crate [constraint](https://mhallin.github.io/juniper/juniper/macro.graphql_scalar!.html), I can only use `&self` as a parameter for the `resolve` function.

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

pub enum Value {
    Int(i64),
    Object(HashMap<String, Value>),
}

pub struct WeatherSettings {
    forecast_days: i64,
}

impl WeatherSettings {
    fn resolve(&self) -> Value {
        let json_object: HashMap<String, Value> = *self.into();
        Value::Object(json_object)
    }
}

impl From<WeatherSettings> for HashMap<String, Value> {
    fn from(weather: WeatherSettings) -> HashMap<String, Value> {
        let mut json_object = HashMap::new();
        json_object.insert("forecast_days".to_owned(),
                           Value::Int(weather.forecast_days));
        return json_object;
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

More directly, I get the error:

```
error: the type of this value must be known in this context
  --> src/main.rs:14:51
   |
14 |         let json_object: HashMap<String, Value> = *self.into();
   |                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> How do I imply the type of the value when there is no type parameters or ascriptions?

In the vast majority of cases, the Rust compiler can infer the generic types of a type or function based on how values of the generic type are used.

In some cases, there isn't enough information to infer exactly one type for a generic type, but there is always a way to pass type parameters when they exist.

The two ways of doing so are to use the *turbofish* or [*fully qualified syntax*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html#fully-qualified-syntax-for-disambiguation-calling-methods-with-the-same-name) at the call site.

### Turbofish

The turbofish is the symbols `::<Type1, Type2, ...>` appended to a function or type. See how it looks like a fish?

#### Function example

[`mem::size_of`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.size_of.html) is defined as:

```
pub const fn size_of<T>() -> usize.
```

You can call it as:

```
std::mem::size_of::<i8>()
//               ^^^^^^ turbofish
```

#### Type example

[`Vec::new`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.new) is defined as:

```
impl<T> Vec<T> {
    pub fn new() -> Vec<T>
}
```

You can call it as:

```
Vec::<u8>::new()
// ^^^^^^ turbofish
```

#### Multiple types

If your function has multiple types, you need to specify something for each type in the same order as the definition:

```
fn example<A, B>() {}

fn main() {
    example::<i32, bool>();
    //         ^A  ^B
}
```

### Fully qualified syntax

If you need to disambiguate a method call to a specific trait with a type parameter, you can use the fully qualified syntax.

[`From::from`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.From.html#tymethod.from) is defined as:

```
trait From<T> {
    fn from(T) -> Self;
}
```

You can call it as:

```
    <String as From<&str>>::from("a")
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ fully qualified syntax
```

### Partially inferring types

If there are multiple types that can be provided but some of them can be inferred, you can still use `_` to allow the compiler to infer that specific type.

---

Here, I use the turbofish on the `Into` type for your code:

```
let json_object = *Into::<HashMap<String, Value>>::into(self);
```

That's not your problem though.

For this line to be valid:

```
let json_object: HashMap<String, Value> = *self.into();
```

The result of the call to `self.into()` must be something that could be dereferenced to produce the type `HashMap<String, Value>`. How is the compiler expected to know what that is? It's also not what you want.

All you have is `&self`, so *that's what you have to convert from*. Implement the trait for a reference to your struct:

```
impl<'a> From<&'a WeatherSettings> for HashMap<String, Value> {
    fn from(weather: &'a WeatherSettings) -> HashMap<String, Value> {
        let mut json_object = HashMap::new();
        json_object.insert("unit".to_owned(), Value::String(weather.unit.clone()));
        json_object.insert("forecast_days".to_owned(), Value::Int(weather.forecast_days));
        json_object.insert("data".to_owned(), Value::String(weather.data.clone()));
        json_object
    }
}
```

This means you cannot move the strings over, but instead have to copy them. That's the restriction placed by the `&self`.