# How do I specify a type that cannot be inferred when using if let?

Tags: rust

I want to write the following with `if let` but `Ok(config)` does not provide the type for `toml::from_str`

```
let result: Result<Config, _> = toml::from_str(content.as_str());
match result {
    Ok(config) => {}
    _ => {}
}

// if let Ok(config) = toml::from_str(content.as_str()) {
//    
// }
```

I tried `Ok(config: Config)` without luck. The success type is not inferred.

Comment: Please review how to create a [MCVE] and then [edit] your question to include it. We cannot tell what crates, types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. Specifically, we don't know what `Config` is. Does it need to be a custom type, or can you use something built in to the language? What is `content`, could it just be a string literal? Ideally, produce something that reproduces your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the `match` or the `if let`; the type specification is provided by the assignment to `result`. This version with `if let` works:

```
extern crate toml;

fn main() {
    let result: Result<i32, _> = toml::from_str("");
    if let Ok(config) = result {
        // ... 
    }
}
```

This version with `match` does not:

```
extern crate toml;

fn main() {
    match toml::from_str("") {
        Ok(config) => {}
        _ => {}
    }
}
```

In most cases, you'll actually *use* the success value. Based on the usage, the compiler can infer the type and you don't need any type specification:

```
fn something(_: i32) {}

match toml::from_str("") {
    Ok(config) => something(config),
    _ => {}
}

if let Ok(config) = toml::from_str("") {
    something(config);
}
```

If for some reason you need to perform the conversion but not use the value, you can use the *turbofish* on the function call:

```
match toml::from_str::<i32>("") {
//                  ^^^^^^^
    Ok(config) => {},
    _ => {}
}

if let Ok(config) = toml::from_str::<i32>("") {
    //                            ^^^^^^^
}
```

See also:

- [How do I imply the type of the value when there are no type parameters or ascriptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41882151/155423)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I don't know why you are unsatisfied with my question and at the same time you answered it perfectly!

Comment: @Pascal Because Shep guess your problem that doesn't make your question good.

Comment: @Stargateur This comment isn't helpful to the OP; other people please don't upvote 'telling people off' comments like this. Come on people; constructive feedback. 'Your question was bad' contributes nothing.

Comment: @Pascal it's very difficult to guess what exactly you were asking in this question; see shepmasters comment on it; in general questions with a bit more detail are much easier to answer. A rust play pen example would have made answering it a lot easier.

Comment: @Doug I don't think this was a "telling off" comment, it feels like a direct response to "why you are unsatisfied with my question and at the same time you answered it". It's true: just because a person could build a MCVE from the original question in order to answer it doesn't make the original question good. OP already has some suggestions on how to improve their question and has chosen to ignore those suggestions.

Comment: @Pascal and downvotes can always be removed when the underlying cause of the downvoting is removed; it's rarely too late to improve a question.