# How can I deserialize a document from MongoDB into a Rust struct?

Tags: mongodb, rust, serde

This is my attempt so far. I don't understand how I can tell Rust to deserialize the MongoDB result into a struct.

I have defined the struct called `Thing` that I would like the data mapped to.

```
#[macro_use(bson, doc)]
extern crate bson;
extern crate mongodb;
#[macro_use]
extern crate serde_derive;

use mongodb::db::ThreadedDatabase;
use mongodb::{Client, ThreadedClient};

fn main() {
    let client =
        Client::connect("localhost", 27017).expect("Failed to initialize standalone client.");

    let coll = client.db("bestestDB").collection("things");

    let doc = doc! {
        "$text": { "$search": "Love" },
    };

    #[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
    pub struct Thing {
        #[serde(rename = "_id")] // Use MongoDB's special primary key field name when serializing
        pub id: String,
        pub name: String,
        pub image: String,
    }

    let mut cursor = coll
        .find(Some(doc.clone()), None)
        .ok()
        .expect("Failed to execute find.");

    let item = cursor.next();

    // cursor.next() returns an Option<Result<Document>>
    match item {
        Some(Ok(doc)) => match bson::from_bson(bson::Bson::Document(doc)) {
            Ok(thing) => println!("{:?}", thing),
            Err(_) => panic!("Deserializing failed!"),
        },
        Some(Err(_)) => panic!("Failed to get next from server!"),
        None => panic!("Server returned no results!"),
    }
}
```

Then I get the following error message:

```
   |
37 | Ok(thing) => println!("{:?}", thing),
   |    ^^^^^ cannot infer type for `_`
```

Comment: How do you expect rust guess you want to transform `doc` to a `Thing` ? https://docs.rs/bson/0.11.1/bson/type.DecoderResult.html, you need to give rust a hint for `T`, something like `bson::from_bson::<Thing>(bson::Bson::Document(doc))`

Comment: I believe your question is answered by the answers of [How do I specify a type that cannot be inferred when using if let?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50841088/155423). If you disagree, please [edit] your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: I'm guessing you need to say `let item: Thing = cursor.next();` or `let item = cursor.next::<Thing>();`

Comment: Stargateur's solution worked! Shepmaster: we can mark it as a duplicate.

Comment: `bson::from_bson(Bson::Document(doc));` https://github.com/mongodb/bson-rust/issues/145

Comment: Now you can do `bson::from_document::<Thing>(doc);`