# Type annotations required for format! when parsing postgres results

Tags: rust

I have some code that's supposed to get image filenames from a database and add them to a vector.

```
extern crate postgres;

use postgres::{Connection, TlsMode};

fn main() {
    let conn = Connection::connect(
        "postgres://postgres:password@localhost:5432/test",
        TlsMode::None,
    ).unwrap();
    let mut filenames = Vec::new();

    if let Ok(filename_results) = conn.query("SELECT filename FROM images", &[]) {
        for row in &filename_results {
            filenames.push(format!("{}.jpg", row.get(0)));
        }
    }

    println!("{:?}", filenames);
}
```

This fails with:

```
error[E0283]: type annotations required: cannot resolve `_: postgres::types::FromSql`
  --> src/main.rs:14:54
   |
14 |                 filenames.push(format!("{}.jpg", row.get(0)));
   |                                                      ^^^
```

I don't understand why Rust can't figure out the type in this context, though I've figured out a way to make it work. I'm wondering what the simplest/idiomatic way to tell `format!()` what types it should be expecting are, and why row.get(0) doesn't need a type annotation unless I slap a format!() around it. This is my best attempt at a solution:

```
for row in &filename_results {
    let filename: String = row.get(0);
    filenames.push(format!("{}.jpg", filename));
}
```

Comment: I believe your question is answered by the answers of [How do I imply the type of the value when there are no type parameters or ascriptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41882151/155423). If you disagree, please [edit] your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: Edited to add surrounding code and cut the struct out. I don't really see how the question you linked is related to mine - at the very least, my skill level doesn't allow me to translate that answer into one for me. My question involves an interaction between psql and format!, and I can't tell if the underlying issue is the same as the one you'd run into when unable to pass parameters other than &self inside an impl{} block, but there are enough differences that I was unable to find that question. I can tell they're both about types, but that's about it.

Comment: The information I got out of your other comment is `row.get::<String>(0)`, which fails since 0 is not a String. `row.get::<_, String>(0)` works though, which is what I was looking for.
Otherwise, is there any reason you think the one-liner style is better? Is it to avoid making 'images' mutable?

Comment: One strange thing about the turbofish that I don't see in your answer is that the first n arguments are the parameters into the function, while the last one specifies the inferred return type. In my case, I don't think it's clear from that answer that I would have to use <_, String> to match the types of 0 and row.get().

Comment: I see, I wasn't familiar with the template syntax but that makes sense now.

Comment: I hope you don't mind. I've written up what you worked out here as an answer. I agree with Timofey that unless you already understand what's going on, it's not obvious that the answer to the linked question also answers this question, so I've tried to explain the connection.

Comment: I realized that my question doesn't allude to the fact that I had no idea what the error even means, which is a big reason why I didn't think the linked answer was a duplicate. I've added to the question to make it more findable and clearer what the confusion is. I'm relatively new to S/O so if I shouldn't be making edits after I've accepted an answer, feel free to revert. Thank you both for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at the signature of the function you're calling:

```
fn get<I, T>(&self, idx: I) -> T 
where
    I: RowIndex + Debug,
    T: FromSql,
```

That is, this function actually has two type parameters, `I` and `T`. It uses `I` as the type to index with. The argument you pass has this type. `T` is the return type. The constraints (the `where` clause) don't really matter here, but they specify that the argument type `I` has to be something postgres can use as a row index, and the return type `T` has to be something postgres can create from an SQL result.

Usually, Rust can infer the type parameters of functions. Argument types are usually easier to infer, because there's a value of the desired type right there. Even C++ can infer argument types! Return types are harder to infer because they depend on the context the function is called from, but Rust can often infer those too.

Let's look at your function call and the context it's used:

```
format!("{}.jpg", row.get(0))
```

Here's it's obvious that the argument is an integer, because it's a literal, and it's right there. There are rules for working out what integer types it could be, but in this case, it has to be `usize` because that's the only one the `RowIndex` trait is implemented for.

But what return type are you expecting? `format!` can take almost any type, so the compiler has no way to know what `get` needs to return. All it knows is that `T` has to have the `FromSql` trait. This is what the error message tells you:

```
error[E0283]: type annotations required: cannot resolve `_: postgres::types::FromSql`
```

Luckily, Rust has a syntax for explicitly passing function parameters to functions, so you don't have to rely on its type inference. Shepmaster wrote a good explanation of it in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41882374/967945) to a similar question. Jumping straight to the answer, you can write `row.get::<_, String>(0)` to only specify the second type parameter, and let inference work on the first type parameter.

You specifically ask for a more idiomatic way to specify the type, and I think what you already have is more idiomatic. With the explicit type parameter, a reader still needs to understand the signature of `get` to know that `String` will be the return type. It's not always the case that the second type parameter will be the return type, and it's easy to get confused and specify them in the wrong order. By naming and type-annotating the result, you make it obvious what value the type annotation refers to.

```
let filename: String = row.get(0);
filenames.push(format!("{}.jpg", filename));
```

If you do want to write your code in the more functional style that Shepmaster suggested, you can still use this style:

```
let filenames = filename_results.map(|row| { let f: String = row.get(0); format!("{}.jpg", f) }).collect();
```

and break the "one-liner" across lines if that suits your taste.