# How do I determine the type annotation while calling MyActor::from_registry() from another actor's handler that doesn't define T?

Tags: rust, rust-actix

I have two Actix actors. `MyActor1` defines a generic trait that one of its fields implements. `MyActor2` doesn't need to define `T` and I can't figure out how to call `MyActor1::from_registry()` from `MyActor2` message handlers without knowing what type `T` maps to.

I've tried variations of this:

```
let addr: Addr<MyActor1<T>> = MyActor1::from_registry();
```

This doesn't work because I don't know where/how to define `T` unless it's also defined on `struct MyActor2<T: Thing>` and then added to the `impl<T> Handler<Msg> for MyActor2<T> where T:...`.

I also tried this but it doesn't work because `Thing` doesn't implement `Default` (because it's a trait):

```
let addr: Addr<MyActor1<Thing>> = MyActor1::from_registry();
```

Here's an example I'm using:

**Cargo.toml**

```
[package]
name = "actix-example"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["me"]
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
actix = "0.8.1"
```

**main.rs**

```
#![allow(dead_code)]

use actix::prelude::*;

trait Thing {
    fn name(&self) {}
}

#[derive(Default)]
struct One;
impl Thing for One {}

#[derive(Default)]
struct Two;
impl Thing for Two {}

// MyActor1
#[derive(Default)]
struct MyActor1<T: Thing> {
    thing: T,
}

impl<T> Actor for MyActor1<T>
where
    T: Thing + 'static + Default,
{
    type Context = Context<Self>;
}
impl<T> Supervised for MyActor1<T> where T: Thing + 'static + Default {}
impl<T> SystemService for MyActor1<T> where T: Thing + 'static + Default {}
impl<T> Handler<Msg> for MyActor1<T>
where
    T: Thing + 'static + Default,
{
    type Result = ();
    fn handle(&mut self, _msg: Msg, _ctx: &mut Context<Self>) {}
}

// MyActor2
#[derive(Default)]
struct MyActor2;

#[derive(Message)]
struct Msg;
impl Actor for MyActor2 {
    type Context = Context<Self>;
}
impl Supervised for MyActor2 {}
impl SystemService for MyActor2 {}

impl Handler<Msg> for MyActor2 {
    type Result = ();
    fn handle(&mut self, _msg: Msg, _ctx: &mut Context<Self>) {
        let addr = MyActor1::from_registry();
    }
}

fn main() {
    let sys = System::new("test");
    let act1 = MyActor1 {
        thing: One::default(),
    };
    let act2 = MyActor2::default();
    actix::SystemRegistry::set(act1.start());
    actix::SystemRegistry::set(act2.start());
    let _ = sys.run();
}
```

When running the code, I get this error:

```
error[E0283]: type annotations required: cannot resolve `_: Thing`
  --> src/main.rs:50:20
   |
50 |         let addr = MyActor1::from_registry();
   |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
note: required by `MyActor1`
  --> src/main.rs:15:1
   |
15 | struct MyActor1<T: Thing> {
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I know this solves this example:

```
let addr: Addr<MyActor1<One>> = MyActor1::from_registry();
```

What would I do if I didn't know what `MyActor1<T>` was at runtime? For example, maybe I had some code to initialize `MyActor1` as `MyActor1<Two>` at runtime based on some command line argument.

Comment: I don't follow the logic behind your question. You have created a generic actor, which means there might be multiple actors with different concrete types (`MyActor1<i32>` and `MyActor1<bool>`, for example). If *you* don't know which actor you want to reference, how would the code?

Comment: Are you literally looking for the syntax `let addr = MyActor1::<One>::from_registry()`?

Comment: If so, this question will be a duplicate of [How do I imply the type of the value when there are no type parameters or ascriptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41882151/155423)

Comment: *maybe I had some code to initialize `MyActor1` as `MyActor1<Two>` at runtime* — that's not how **statically** typed languages work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR: `MyActor1` is not a type, it's a blueprint.**

---

When you declare `struct Foo<T>`, `Foo` is not a type, it's a blueprint for the compiler to create types, or, as computer science would have it, a **type constructor**.

If you have the blueprints for a house, you cannot open the door of the blueprint and go for a nap in the bedroom: there is no bedroom, there is an idea of what the bedroom will look like once the house is built.

The same thing applies here. You cannot use a *type constructor* where a *type* is needed.

---

You are left with 3 solutions:

- Make `MyActor1` a type, removing the parameter `T`; for example, it may store `T` as a `Box<Thing>`.
- Make `MyActor2` a generic, adding the parameter `T`.
- Implement some run-time discovery, for example using a type-map.

Which is the best solution in your case will vastly depend on your use case, and I am loathe to give any advice based on a reduced example.