# Allow `i` to be `u64` in a `for` loop over `Range`

Tags: rust

Simple question, can't find an answer anywhere:

```rust
for i in 0..65000000000 {
    do_something;
}
```

Throws an error:

> literal out of range for `i32`

Setting this to a larger type also does not work:

```rust
for i: u64 in 0..65000000000 {
    do_something;
}
```

Throws an error:

> error: missing `in` in `for` loop

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to declare the type of the variable in Rust for loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24463655/is-it-possible-to-declare-the-type-of-the-variable-in-rust-for-loops)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/loop-expr.html#iterator-loops) :

> ```
> Syntax
> IteratorLoopExpression :
>    for Pattern in Expression except struct expression BlockExpression
> ```

It expects a **Pattern** not a declaration.

You need to set the type explicitly by changing the input's type.

```rust
for i in 0..65000000000u64 {
    do_something;
}
```