# Why doesnt my rust program compile when i use 64 bit unsigned integers instead of 32 bit?

Tags: rust, fibonacci

When I try to make my fibonacci evaluator calculate `u64` integers the compiler gets upset and refuses to compile. I thought this was built in, but it says "missing crate or module".

```
error: expected one of `@` or `|`, found `:`
  --> src/main.rs:15:12
   |
15 |     for fib: u64 in r {
   |            ^
   |            |
   |            expected one of `@` or `|`
   |            help: maybe write a path separator here: `::`

error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared crate or module `fib`
  --> src/main.rs:15:9
   |
15 |     for fib: u64 in r {
   |         ^^^ use of undeclared crate or module `fib`
```

This code compiles fine without any issues when I use plain old `u32` integers:

```rust
use std::io;
use std::ops::Range;

fn main() {
    println!("Please enter a fibonacci number to evaluate to:");
    let mut n: String = String::new();
    io::stdin().read_line(&mut n).expect("Not a number");

    let mut _n: u32 = n.trim().parse().expect("Please type a number!");

    let mut r: Range<u32> = Range { start: 0, end: _n };

    let mut fib: u32 = 0;

    for fib in r {
        fibonacci(fib);

        println!("The fibonacci number is {}", fibonacci(fib));
    }
}

fn fibonacci(n: u32) -> u32 {
    match n {
        0 => 1,
        1 => 1,
        _ => fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2),
    }
}
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please post the text of your compiler error(s) as text rather than an image or a link to an image. [ask]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to declare the type of the variable in Rust for loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24463655/is-it-possible-to-declare-the-type-of-the-variable-in-rust-for-loops)

Answer (score 1):

The type of the iteration variable is implied by the iterator. You can't annotate it with a type, because then the iteration variable would just be of the wrong type.

Instead, consider changing the type of `r`:

```
let mut r: Range<u64> = Range{start:0,end: _n};
```

---

Other notes:

- The declaration `let mut fib:u32 = 0;` is useless; this variable is never used.  (`for fib` creates a new variable named `fib` scoped to the loop.)
- You will have to update `fn fibonacci(n: u32) -> u32` to accept and return `u64`.
- You probably should also update `_n` to be `u64`.
- Consider running your code through `rustfmt` to fix the wildly inconsistent indentation.

Comment: Extra note: integer ranges are usually created with the `0 .. _n` syntax rather than the more verbose `Range`.